# Resolving Laravel 5.5 cookie not set in request header that result in Page inactivity upon login

Tags: laravel, cookies

I am running Laravel 5.5 application in local development machine and in windows server 2012 production and there is no problem. However, when I deployed my application to Centos 6 Linux, the application produce Page inactivity error upon login. Investigation reveal that the cause of the error is that the request header cookie is not set.

My request header that works in my local development machine as follows:

```
...
Cache-Control   max-age=0
Connection  keep-alive
Cookie  XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6InlGZ0l3OUV…3OGEzNWY5MDliOWVmZjYifQ%3D%3D
Host    localhost
Referer http://localhost/abc/public/
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests   1
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; …) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0
```

Response header as follows

```
...
Keep-Alive  timeout=5, max=100
Server  Apache/2.4.29 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2l PHP/7.1.11
Set-Cookie  XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6InFaMzI0QjV…:41 GMT; Max-Age=1799; path=/
Set-Cookie  abc_app_session=eyJpdiI…5MjBkIn0%3D; path=/; HttpOnly
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
X-Powered-By PHP/7.1.11
```

The corresponding request and response header from my linux production as follows

**Request:**

```
Connection keep-alive
Host    www.abc.com
x-https 1
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests   1
User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; …) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0
```

**Response:**

```
Connection  Keep-Alive
Content-Type    text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date    Sun, 24 Jun 2018 14:49:22 GMT
Keep-Alive  timeout=5, max=100
Server  Apache
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
```

Without the XSRF token in the cookie, there is no way that Laravel 5.5 can verify against the session in the server and thus it will cause page inactivity. I have no clue but suspect it could be Linux permission issue that prevent cookie from being passed between client and server. I am using https connection for Linux. I tried the following but it is not working:

1- Using php artisan config:cache to clear all old cache and session 
2- using php artisan view:clear to clear all  views 
3- chmod 755 to set permission to bootstrap/cache and storage folder recursively 
4- chown apache to change owner grup of both bootstrap/cache and storage to apache. 
5- session_driver=file 
   session_encrypt=false
   Cache_driver=file
6-  'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),
'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', false),
'http_only' => true,

I am running out of clue what is the cause of the issue and how to fix it. Any help is appreciated.